# Bootbox alert throw "Uncaught TypeError: div.on is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootbox

I use bootbox to display information and decision messages to the user, but he accuses the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: div.on is not a function". Can someone help me solve?

Below my code:

```
<html>
    <script src="js/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"></link>
    <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript' src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript' src="js/bootbox.js"></script>
    ...

    jQuery("#datagrid").navButtonAdd('#pdatagrid', {
      caption : '', title : 'Alerta', buttonicon : "ui-icon-link", onClickButton : function () {
        top.Base.getUtil().alerta('alerta acionado');
      }
    });
```

My internal framework method

```
alerta: function(message){
    bootbox.alert( message );
},
```

In bootbox.js the error "div.on is not a function" occurs at line 409

```
    // hook into the modal's keyup trigger to check for the escape key
    div.on('keyup.dismiss.modal', function(e) {
        // any truthy value passed to onEscape will dismiss the dialog
        // as long as the onEscape function (if defined) doesn't prevent it
        if (e.which === 27 && options.onEscape) {
            onCancel('escape');
        }
    });
```

Comment: `on()` is a jQuery method.  `div` is apparently not a jQuery object instance.

Comment: Would be helpful to know which version of Bootbox you're using - the code you're referring to doesn't exist in the current master branch.

Comment: Bootbox is a component in an internal framework used by the application, when I call the native method "bootbox.alert" works. I will have to see the architecture of this framework to solve the problem.